# the results of my foreach loop in my browse view is not displaying asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

My aim is to display in the (browse View) all movies that are has a status as "recent" appear however not when loading the website not movies that has a status of "recent" appear.
Tried to create a LINQ query in action method to produce a list of movies that has status of "recent".

```
namespace Cinema1.Models
{
    [Bind(Exclude = "MovieId")]
    public class Movie
    {
        public int MovieId { get; set; }
        public int MovieGenreId { get; set; }
        public int MovieStatusId { get; set; }

        public virtual MovieStatus MovieStatus { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<MovieGenre> MovieGenre { get; set; }
```

//model class for movie status

```
namespace Cinema1.Models
{
    public class MovieStatus
    {
        [Key]


        public int MovieStatusId { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
```

//Store Controller

```
            public ActionResult Browse(string q)
            {

                var statusModel = storeDB.Movies
                                    .Include("MovieStatus")
                                    .Where(a => a.Title.Contains(q))
                                    .Take(1);


                return View(statusModel.ToList());





//seed database

         Namespace Cinema1.Models
    {
        public class CinemaInitializer : System.Data.Entity.DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<CinemaContext>
        {
            protected override void Seed(CinemaContext context)
            {
                CinemaContext storeDB = new CinemaContext();

                context.Movies.Add(new Movie
                {
                    MovieId = 01,
                    Title = "Blair Witch",
                    Rating = 15,
                    MovieStatusId = 2,
                    MovieStatus = new MovieStatus { Status = "Recent" },
                    Cast = "Corbin Reid, Wes Robinson, Valorie Curry",
                    Director = "Adam Wingard",
                    RunningTimeMins = 89,
                    Language = "English",
                    Synopsis = "It’s been 20 years since James’ sister disappeared into the Black Hills Forest.         
                MovieDates.ForEach(s => context.MovieDates.Add(s));
                context.SaveChanges();





//the View for Browse action controller

    @model  IEnumerable<Cinema1.Models.Movie> 

    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Browse";
    }

    <h2>Movie status</h2>

    <p>
        Select from @Model.Count() Status:
    </p>


       <ul>
            @foreach (var Movies in Model)
            {
                <li>
                    @Movies.Title
                </li>
                <li>@Movies.MovieStatus.Status</li>
            }
        </ul>
```

Comment: In your  Browse` action method you are not getting movies with the "recent" status. you have where condition which does a search on the movie title property. Why do you think you should be seeing items with "recent" status ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My aim is to display in the (browse) all movies that are
>   catagorized/has a status as "recent".At the moment in my view the @model.count() works...output is zero. However should it not be one since one movie has a status on recent?

In your Browse action method you do not have the code to get the movies with status "recent". Instead you have code to get a subset of movies which has the word you pass in querystring "q" in the Movie Title! Why do you expect that code to return movies with status "recent" ???

If you want to get movies with status "Recent", you should have a where clause which checks that. The below code should do that.

```
public ActionResult Browse()
{
    var statusModel = storeDB.Movies.Include("MovieStatus")
                                    .Where(g => g.MovieStatus.Name == "Recent");           

    return View(statusModel.ToList());
}
```

Now this is going to give you always the movies with "Recent" status. If you want this to be dynamic based on the querystring, you can add a parameter to this method which takes a status name. You can set the default value to "Recent" so that even if you do not pass a status name in querystring, by default, it will use the status parameter value as "Recent"

```
public ActionResult Browse(string status="Recent")
{
    var statusModel = storeDB.Movies.Include("MovieStatus")
                                    .Where(g => g.MovieStatus.Name == status);           

    return View(statusModel.ToList());
}
```

Comment: this did not work, when I load my website this is what appears: Movie status
Select from 0 Status://as you can see nothing seems to be loaded as in any movies with the status "Recent". I really do not know were I am going wrong. I would really appreciate any help with this. Thanks for before

Comment: **Movie status Select from 0 Status:** What does this mean ? I am not quite following what you meant here. As i mentioned in the answer, the code in the question you had does not makes any sense in terms of your expected output. In your question you said you wanted to show the movies with status "Recent" and the code in the answer should give you that. When you say "this did not work", can you be more specific ? What specifically did not work ?

Comment: I altered the actionresult Browse code as you suggested. The result I was hoping for was that when the website loads the movie "Blair Witch" should appear as when seeding the database the "Blair Witch" movie had been given a status of "Recent" . I just want a web page were any movie that has a status of "Recent" is shown on my website. thanks

Comment: The above code should give you any movies with the status "Recent". If you are not getting that, that means you do not have the proper data or you are not completely following the answer code.

Comment: instead of "Blair Witch" being outputted onto the website (since it had a status of "Recent", this was outputted onto my website: Movie status Select from 0 Status

Comment: Verify your data. The code is nothing complex. It is just querying data with that status. I doubt you do not have correct data.

Comment: does my seed database code look incorrect? spent days on this and do not know were I am going wrong

Comment: I do not know your seed code is correct or not as your question was about getting data and you mentioned you have data in the table. I suggest you split your issue into isolated problems. First make sure that seeding works fine.

Comment: Managed to solve the problem, error was in my Movie Date model class.